# What does it mean "... the economy goes arse over tit."?

Tags: meaning, slang

I've found this turn of speech here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=429146.msg4691806#msg4691806

> which I'm sure is quite alarming and effective to the average ignorant
>   pleb who is then happy to shell out £100 on a subscription if it means
>   he now has the secrets to hold onto his money when the economy goes
>   arse over tit.

What does it mean "goes arse over tit." ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Wiktionary, **[arse over tit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arse_over_tit)** means,

> *(Australia, New Zealand, UK, idiomatic, vulgar)* Tumbling; falling; upside-down; unstable or unbalanced.
>   *I missed the step and went **arse over tit**.*

When the economy went that way, it means that it's unstable, tumbling down. It means everything about the economy went wrong.

Another similar phrase, but more common (to me) and less vulgar, is *the economy is **tumbling down***.

Some other similar expressions (but might be used differently, see J.R.'s comment below) are *head over heels*, *base over apex*, and *topsy-turvy*.

Comment: Is it verbatim means: "Goes to the asshole through chest"?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. I think the example *I missed the step and went ...* gives you a better picture.

Comment: It means ass (not asshole) went over breast (breast can mean chest generally, but tit is slang for a woman's breast). Basically, the bottom of your body is going over your top, as if you are rolling over yourself. It means the same as "head over heels", in which your feet go over your head.

Comment: A similar expression is "tits up", which has similar connotations and would be fine for OP's example. "It's all well and good till the economy goes tits up".

Comment: @DamkerngT. - Except _head over heels_ usually implies something more emotional and positive: _She fell head-over-heels in love with him._ It may be less vulgar, but I wouldn't say, _"...when the economy goes head over heels"_ – not when I mean that it's crashing.

Comment: @J.R. How about *it is tumbling down* or *it goes topsy-turvy*?

Comment: _Tumbling down_ would be a good way to describe the same meaning with less vulgar wording.

Comment: @Damkerng T, `I missed the step and went .` i.e. `Economy missed the tit and goes to the ass`. Is this turn of speach near the food field? Why there is a tit, half of woman's breast? And arse is a light version of asshole. Why is this turn of speech on the woman's side?

Comment: The expression doesn't mean that the economy missed the tit and goes to the ass. Here is a picture of a kid doing a [tumbling](http://www.flipztumblinggym.com/uploads/3/7/3/9/3739355/s375140269123120_p2_i1_w745.jpeg). As one of the learners, it's usually unfruitful to dissect idioms literally, or pursue its origin. So though I know that arse usually means just ass, not a hole, I couldn't explain why it's just tit (not a tit), or why it has to based on female organs. Just as we couldn't tell why it's *[a thumbs up](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13964/is-it-thumb-is-up-in-thumbs-up)*.

Comment: @AnomalousAwe - "arse over tit" simply means that your buttocks are _over_ – that is, _physically higher than_ – your chest as you tumble. [This person](http://photographicdictionary.com/sites/photographicdictionary.com/files/photos/s/somersault.jpg) could be said to be "arse over tit," because their butt is up in the air. [This person](http://mckenzieyouthgroup.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/walking-on-ice-286x300.jpg%3Fw%3D540) is slipping & falling, too, but not "arse over tit," because their butt is still lower than their chest. The expression is a way of emphasizing the degree of the tumble.

Comment: It's just a coarser way of saying `head over heels`.

Comment: @AnomalousAwe `arse` is the British spelling/pronouciation of `ass`. It means your backside/bum/bottom. It's different to `arsehole` (or `asshole`) which means your anus.

Comment: I've also heard "Ass over teakettle"; same idea-the image of a person tumbling.  I would say that "tit's up" is different, that that implies a dead person lying on her back.